# How to upload files with Axios / Vue with <script setup> to Django REST API backend

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I have both Vue frontend / Django REST API backend repository setup below.
I am struggling to find a way to send the file to the Django backend.

**Django backend**
https://github.com/TraitOtaku/Vue-File-Upload

**Vue frontend**
https://github.com/TraitOtaku/Django-Rest-API-for-Fileupload

I was able to confirm that I can upload the files with the Django API interface(image below)
[Django API interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vctT6.png)

and also using the postman desktop app.

My specific problem here is that when the user selects the file, I don't know how to attach the file data to the POST request.

In the Vue repo, there is an App.vue and form inside the vue file.

```
<template>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    formState:{{ formState }}
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group my-2">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">File Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" v-model="formState.name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group my-2">
        <label class="form-label" for="customFile">Upload Store Documents</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="storeFile"
          @change="appendFile(event.target.name, event.target.files)" />
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="createStoreDoc">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <h1>Store Documents</h1>
    <div v-if="storeDoc">
      <div v-for="doc in storeDoc" :key="doc.id">
        <div>
          File ID:{{ doc.id }}
        </div>
        <div>
          File Name:{{ doc.name }}
        </div>
        <div>
          File Content:{{ doc.file }}
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import axios from "axios";
import { ref, toRaw, reactive } from "vue";

const formState = reactive({
  name: "",
  file: null,
});


const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/store-doc/",
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    // Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

const storeDoc = ref(null)
const getStoreDoc = () => {
  apiClient.get()
    .then((response) => {
      storeDoc.value = response.data
      // console.log(storeDoc)
    })
}
getStoreDoc()


const createStoreDoc = () => {
  apiClient.post('', toRaw(formState))
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("success!" + response.data);
      getStoreDoc()
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}



</script>
```

I have this POST request createStoreDoc() and this will work but won't attach file to the request yet.

I want to achieve this with  or composition API, not Options API.
Please feel free to fork the repo to answer this question.

Thank you for reading and lending your knowledge.

Comment: Instead of `application/json`, i would use `multipart/form-data`, and use `new FormData(toRaw(formState))`, you won't be able to upload a file that is part of a json, the file will be stripped during JSON.stringify call, if it's what you are trying to do

Comment: It's to late to edit but FormData takes a form element, not an object, use `let formData = new FormData()` and use `formData.append()` to add fields to it instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how i would do it :

you replace `application/json` by `multipart/form-data` in the `Content-Type` header :

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/store-doc/",
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    // Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
});
```

and make a FormData instance and append your data to it  inside createStoreDoc function :

```
const createStoreDoc = () => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('name', formState.name);
  formData.append('file', formState.file, 'filename.docx');
  apiClient.post('', formData)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("success!" + response.data);
      getStoreDoc()
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

request that is being made at this point :

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/store-doc/' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDhFZwmF0hYfGZyHU' \
  --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryDhFZwmF0hYfGZyHU\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\ntest\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryDhFZwmF0hYfGZyHU\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"\r\n\r\nnull\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryDhFZwmF0hYfGZyHU--\r\n' \
  --compressed
```

Here we see the file in the form data but it's null, because there is an error on the input so we fix it :

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="storeFile"
          @change="appendFile($event.target.name, $event.target.files)" />
```

then, it's still null in the formState because of that error :

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:218 Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.appendFile is not a function
```

So we fix it by adding that appendFile function :

```
const formState = reactive({
  name: "",
  file: null,
  filename: null
});

const appendFile = (name, files) => {
    formState.filename = name;
    formState.file = files[0];
}
```

as a side note, we added the filename in the state and used it in the createStoreDoc function :

```
formData.append('file', formState.file, formState.filename);
```

and we get that request :

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/store-doc/' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0p7GnwTxmLgGiCHx' \
  --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundary0p7GnwTxmLgGiCHx\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\ntest\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary0p7GnwTxmLgGiCHx\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.docx"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary0p7GnwTxmLgGiCHx--\r\n' \
  --compressed
```

File is uploaded as binary data

[image]

Comment: IT WORKED!!! I had to change to `formData.append('file', formState.file);` instead of `formData.append('file', formState.file, 'filename.docx');` I am not aware what the last `'filename.docx'` does. Thank you!

Comment: well it's the name of the file

Comment: I see, Thank you for explaining it so well. I hope you have a wonderful day. You are awesome!